# How to exclude a hidden MacOS folder like Library/Spotify from Time Machine?

Tags: macos, directory, spotify, hidden, timemachine

After figuring out that **Time Machine** always commits a lot of stuff whenever I use Spotify (using `sudo tmutil compare "path1" "path2"` ), I wanted to **remove Spotify** from being backed up. In the time machine options, it is easy to add folders to be ignored. So I added Spotify from the application folder. However, I wanted to ignore also

```
/Users/***/Library/Application Support/Spotify/PersistentCache
```

for every user, but was not able to do so. The problem is that `Library` does not show up in the final dialog, being sort of a **hidden folder**.

Any hints to solve this?

Comment: How about *"unhiding"* it? https://www.noterepeat.com/articles/how-to/70-mac-os-x-accessing-hidden-library-folders

Comment: @MarkSetchell that sounds like a viable solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use this shortcut when the dialog opens.

```
CMD + Shift + .
```